# What to do when the DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary doubles the amount of bytes in my bytearray?

Tags: java, arrays, string, server, client

I'm trying to stablish a communication protocol with a secure server. The server, in some point, waits my asymmetrically ciphered symmetric key byte array with a length of 128 bytes, but after I use the DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary to convert the array of bytes into a String, and after I use it it doubles the amount of bytes in the array. I want to know why does this happens and how to solve it?

Using different types of methods that parse byte[] into String, but the server doesn't recognize them.

Here is the code I'm using:

**Note: The public key is sent by the server when sending the Digital Certificate.

For the cipher:

```
private static byte[] cifradoAsimetrico(SecretKey key, PublicKey publicKey) {
    byte[] cipheredText;
    try {           
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(asimetrico);         
        byte[] clearText = key.getEncoded();            
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        cipheredText = cipher.doFinal(clearText);
        return cipheredText;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("[Exception] Method cifradoAsimetrico( ): " + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

For the communication protocol:

```
keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(simetrico,new BouncyCastleProvider());
keyGenerator.init(128);
    desKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();

byte[] llaveCifrada = cifradoAsimetrico(desKey, publicaServidor);

System.out.println("Tamaño cifrada: " + llaveCifrada.length);
    String llaveCifradaHexa = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(llaveCifrada);

    System.out.println("Tamaño hexa: "+llaveCifradaHexa.getBytes().length);

    socketPrintWriter.println(llaveCifradaHexa);
```

//Algo en el código está generando un problema y el tamaño de lo que se envía es de 256 bytes,
//por eso el servidor no lo recibe. NO PUDIMOS ENCONTRAR LA RAZÓN.

//The server stops here and shows an illegalblocksizeexception data must not be longer than 128 bytes